# In Laravel using the old helper, how to check value of old('value', 'default') when 'value' is an array and 'default' is a basic value?

Tags: forms, laravel, checkbox, default

Say I have checkboxes. Each with a value that goes into the array when checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="card_type1" name="card_type[]" value="easy" @if(old('card_type') != NULL && in_array('easy', old('card_type')) || old('foo', $parkingLot->m_plots_can_easycard) === '1') checked @endif>
<input type="checkbox" id="card_type2" name="card_type[]" value="icash" @if(old('card_type') != NULL && in_array('icash', old('card_type')) || old('foo', $parkingLot->m_plots_can_icash20) === '1') checked @endif>
<input type="checkbox" id="card_type3" name="card_type[]" value="ipass" @if(old('card_type') != NULL && in_array('ipass', old('card_type')) || old('foo', $parkingLot->m_plots_can_ipass) === '1') checked @endif>
```

Upon loading my form first time, I want to reflect the database value. If a value in the DB is '1', check the checkbox. I then modify the checkboxes - checking some and unchecking some - and submit the form and say the form submission fails. I then want to reflect the old values by checking whether each value is in the old checkbox array, checking the checkboxes if so.

My problem is that `old('value', 'default')` consists of both 'value' and 'default' and I can't really use separate methods to determine whether the checkbox should be checked. And if I do (as in above), then I can't just have `old('default')` - and do a separate check there - because having one parameter makes it `old('value')`.

I'm not sure how to go about it in my situation. Any pointers or help would be much appreciated. I hope I illustrated clear enough what my situation is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following

```
<input type="checkbox" id="card_type1" name="card_type[]" value="easy" 
    @if (in_array('easy', old('card_type', [$parkingLot->m_plots_can_easycard === '1' ? 'easy' : '']))) 
        checked 
    @endif>
<input type="checkbox" id="card_type2" name="card_type[]" value="icash" 
    @if (in_array('icash', old('card_type', [$parkingLot->m_plots_can_icash20 === '1' ? 'icash' : '']))) 
        checked 
    @endif>
<input type="checkbox" id="card_type3" name="card_type[]" value="ipass" 
    @if (in_array('ipass', old('card_type', [$parkingLot->m_plots_can_ipass === '1' ? 'ipass' : '']))) 
        checked 
    @endif>
```

Comment: What a smart solution. So basically you convert the default value to an array of value so you can use the same method to check for value in the array?

Comment: @BenKao Yes converting default value we can use a single call to `in_array`. Did it output the values as you expected.

Comment: Yes I tested it and I couldn't find problems with it. Can I ask whether a check of whether the array is null is necessary like is_array()?

Comment: I guess you wouldn't need that as the default passed is always an array and the `card_type` is also defined as an array. But if a user messes around with code and change the input from `card_type[]` to `card_type` you will need that. To get around that you can wrap the `old` method call inside `array_wrap` like `array_wrap(old('card_type', [$parkingLot->m_plots_can_ipass === '1' ? 'ipass' : '']))`

Comment: There seems to be a problem. When I uncheck all boxes and submit form and get it to fail, checkboxes go to the default values. Few things to notice: old card_type array is empty and default shouldn't be relevant anymore???

Comment: That happen because when you uncheck all checkboxes `card_type` won't be in the input array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151944/discussion-between-ben-kao-and-chanafdo).

Comment: Conclusion of chat is that we use hidden input with same name e.g <input type="hidden" name="card_type[]"> to make card_type always present in input.